# Angular ui.grid infinite scroll is not being called second time onwords

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll, angular-ui-grid

My infinite scroll is not working 2nd time onward. I mean it loads the data first time while scrolling, after loading it also append the data to my data set but again if I scroll then it does not calling my load method.

Attached Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/y19med4Xdp73x2Be13ZK?p=preview). Removed $http code with $timeout to reproduce problem on plunker. $timeout also same problem persist.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.infiniteScroll']);

    angular.module('plunker').controller('ListController',ListController);
    ListController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', '$q'];                              
    function ListController  ( $scope,   $timeout,   $q) {
     $scope.itemsPerPage = 20;
     $scope.lastPage = 0;
     $scope.data = [];
     
     var request = {"startAt" : "1","noOfRecords" : $scope.itemsPerPage};
     
     $scope.gridOptions = {
      infiniteScrollDown: true,
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'id', name:'ID'},
        { field: 'name', name:'My Name'}
      ],
      data: 'data',
      onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
        gridApi.infiniteScroll.on.needLoadMoreData($scope, $scope.loadMoreData);
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      }
   };
     
   
    $scope.loadMoreData = function() {
      var promise = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function () {
           //Sample Data Creation Start
        var arrayObj = [];
        for(var i=0; i<$scope.itemsPerPage; i++){
          arrayObj.push({id:Math.random()*100, name:'Name '+Math.random()});
        }
           //Sample Data Creation End
        $scope.data = $scope.data.concat(arrayObj);
      console.log($scope.data);
      promise.resolve();
      }, Math.random()*1000);
      return promise.promise;
   };
  
    $scope.loadMoreData();
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ListController">
    <div data-ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" data-ui-grid-infinite-scroll></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Seems I am missing some event attachment after 1st scroll down load.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed missing the notification, that your new data was loaded.

`$scope.gridApi.infiniteScroll.dataLoaded()`

Here is an updated version of [your Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/h4wUgczEEZu3jPW60ETd?p=preview). See line 36 in app.js.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is working good. But I am facing a new problem while all of my content finished loading scroll bar is not staying on last result. It jumps to last few result. Here is another question I posted related to that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665641/how-to-stop-infinite-scrolling-of-ui-grid-while-content-loading-finish