# How to know that this is the last page on ui-grid pagination in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This is pagination api for to call the pagination with angularjs and ui-grid

```
gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function(newPage, pageSize)
{
  var grid = this.grid;
  paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
  paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
  alert('newPage=' + newPage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to determine on each call that there is any more data or not. ui-grid can not determine because it is a client side programming.

I had faced a similer kind of problem and here is my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665641/how-to-stop-infinite-scrolling-of-ui-grid-while-content-loading-finish).

Here I have checked in `if($scope.lastPage < $scope.maxPage){`

But you can pass some data as `isLastPage = true` from server side on each call and need to save it on `$scope`.